# Data Types in Tags in Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, collections, tags, type-conversion

**Custom.tag**

```
<%@attribute name="setValue" required="true"  rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@attribute name="setColection" required="true"  rtexprvalue="true" %>
```

can we restrict the name with data type or collection . i.e **setName** take only **int** and **setCollection** take only **Collection** i.e. List or **ArrayList**

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Use the type attribute:

```
<%@attribute name="setValue" required="true"  rtexprvalue="true" type="java.lang.Integer" %>
<%@attribute name="setColection" required="true"  rtexprvalue="true" type="java.util.List" %>
```

I would also rename the attributes to `value` and `collection` or `items`.